# Translate model field names in Django Rest Framework serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, translation

How to translate model field names in Django Rest Framework serializers.

I am working on a django project and django rest framework(DRF) and I need to return the translated fields of a model in french if the user selects 'french' or in english if the user selects 'english'. So how to do that, please?
I tried to translate field names in the serializer using gettext_lazy

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class TranslatedCharField(serializers.CharField):
    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        field_names = super().get_field_names(declared_fields, info)
        translated_field_names = [str(_('title')).lower() if field_name == 'title' else field_name for field_name in field_names]
        return translated_field_names
    
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = TranslatedCharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','about']
```

I tried to do that using some third party packages such as:

1. drf-extensions
2. drf-translations
3. django-rest-framework-translate

but still not working...

Answer (score 1):

The `get_field_names` is a method on `ModelSerializer` and not the `serializers.CharField`. You can check it in the Django-REST-framework [code over here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.x/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1068).

Now, fixing your example, it should look like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class TranslatedPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    about = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'about']

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        field_names = super().get_field_names(declared_fields, info)
        translated_field_names = [
            str(_('Title')).lower() if field_name == 'title' else field_name
            for field_name in field_names
        ]
        return translated_field_names
```

Ideally, all field names should be translated to have consistency in the application, but in the above example, I've left it only to work with the title since that is indicated in your question. Please also note that I'm using [`gettext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext) method above instead of [`gettext_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy). This is because in serializer we need to immediately get the translated text to render a response, unlike Models where a lazy evaluation is desired.

Now, following a DRY approach in programming, this feature is much suited as a Mixin instead like:

```
class TranslationFieldMixin(object):
    def get_field_names(self, *args, **kwargs):
        field_names = super().get_field_names(*args, **kwargs)
        translated_field_names = [
            str(_(field_name))
            for field_name in field_names
        ]
        return translated_field_names
```

Now, you can add this mixin to any Model Serializer to convert its field names like this:

```
class PostSerializer(TranslationFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pass
```

Finally, ensure you've [correctly configured your Django application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/) to support translations using Django PO and MO files for the language you're expecting the translation to happen for.

For more details, you can refer to this talk on [supporting translations in Django](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiZ_1gsS4F8&ab_channel=DjangoConUS)

**Disclaimer**: The aforementioned discourse was presented by myself regarding Django translations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I tried both approaches you mentioned,  I also added field translation in django.po file, as follows :                                 #: translation/serializers.py:15
msgid "title"
msgstr "titre"                                                                 and run compilemessages command,                                                      
but I still have 'title' as field name in the response.

Comment: @JaweherBenSalah Can you try to see if the language is correctly activated via `get_language` method from `django.utils.translation`?  Also, then try to print the gettext for the `title` that you need.

Comment: Hi @JaweherBenSalah Did it work for you?